# Empty variables in xcode's variable view while debugging cocoapod pod

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have a problem debugging swift pods in my project.
We've created a swift pod and integrated that into one of our projects as a development pod.
Everything runs great. However, when we try to debug the code in the pod, we don't see any values.

I've checked and we don't strip debug symbols in the Pods project nor in the main project.
What else can be wrong. How do we fix this?

[image: variables view]

### Here is some output from when i 'po' the variables:

[image]

### Here are the buildsettings of my project (not of the Pods project)

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run `po vc` or `po` with any of the other variable names?

Comment: Unfortunatly not Keith...

Comment: Is there an error when you attempt to `po` them? If so can you add that here?

Comment: I have a similar problem and the error I get is
```error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'vc'```

Answer (score 1):

I had exact the same issue, few days ago. My solution was setting optimization flag in Build Settings to none:

```
SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";
```

This is the key when you open it as Source Code.

Optimization Level is inside UI, under code generation. Keep fast for the release since you don't need variables for release :)

Comment: Thnx. But we already have that setting on -Onone (otherwise our builds take way too long to be productive)

Comment: Have you checked do you build just DWARF or DWARD with DSYM ? it's under Debug Information Format

Comment: We have DWARF with DSYM's on.
I've added a screenshot of my buildsettings.